# How to sample near optimal solutions?

Tags: optimization, sampling, sampling-theory

I have a function $f(x)$ that is strongly convex and the minimum of $f(x)$ is obtained at point $x^*$. I want to sample some $x\in \{x: ||x-x^*||<c \ {and} \ ||f(x)-f(x^*)||<d \}$. Is there a rigorous way to uniformly sample some $x$?

Comment: Shouldn't it depend on $f(x)$. I mean we only know convexity of $||x : f(x)-f(x^*)||<d$ and nothing else?

Comment: damnit, I had this same question and I excitedly open this one.. only to see no answer.